# Can we use Google Ads in a Window Forms (.Net) application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-ads-api

Google Ads is used on many websites (and web applications). Can I use Google Ads in .Net Forms application? Does anybody know an API for this?

Comment: Seems not, but there are many other ad suppliers.

Comment: you should probably specify web forms then,  forms usually refers to winforms

Comment: @Chris It would be for a Windows Forms application.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Google Adsense is not allowed in any desktop applications.

From Adsense policy

> "Google ads, search boxes or search results may not be:
>   - **Integrated into a software application of any kind, including toolbars.**
>   - Displayed in pop-ups or pop-unders.
>   - Placed in emails, email programs, or chat programs.
>   - Obscured by elements on a page.
>   - Placed on any non-content-based page. (Does not apply to AdSense for search or mobile      AdSense for search.)
>   - Placed on pages published specifically for the purpose of showing ads.
>   - Placed on pages whose content or URL could confuse users into thinking it is associated      with Google due to the misuse of logos, trademarks or other brand features.
>   - Placed on, within or alongside other Google products or services in a manner that    violates the policies of that product or service"

[www.google.com/adsense/policies](http://www.google.com/adsense/policies)

Answer (score 1):

And still if you want to do it then use web browser control in your application and give it the url , this url should be the page which will contain google ads..

Answer (score 0):

it is only for web application not in desktop application ,Try to catch add yourself for the application.

[for more details Google Adsence](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=48182&gsessionid=i-PZpKHrD1Q06gn7f_55VA)